# aws_alb_target_group not dropping aws_alb_listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When I do a change in my `aws_alb_target_group` and terraform says will drop it, it fails because there is a listener:

```
Target group '' is currently in use by a listener or a rule
```

Listener is:

```
resource "aws_alb_listener" "https" {
  depends_on        = [aws_alb_target_group.target-group]
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.tableau-lb.arn

  protocol = "HTTPS"
  port     = "443"

  ssl_policy      = ""
  certificate_arn = ""

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.target-group.arn
    type             = "forward"
  }
```

And `aws_alb_target_group`:

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "target-group" {
  name = "${var.namespace}-group"

  port        = 80
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  target_type = "instance"

  health_check {
    healthy_threshold   = var.health_check_healthy_threshold
    unhealthy_threshold = var.health_check_unhealthy_threshold
    timeout             = var.health_check_timeout
    interval            = var.health_check_interval
    path                = var.path
  }

  tags = {
    Name = var.namespace
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = false
  }

  depends_on = [aws_lb.tableau-lb]
}

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      default_action.0.target_group_arn,
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a way to destroy fisrt the listener and then the target_group?
I though that with the depens_on should work but doesnt seems to have effect.

```
An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.ec2.aws_alb_target_group.target-group must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_alb_target_group" "target-group" {
      ~ arn                                = "" -> (known after apply)
      ~ arn_suffix                         = "" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                                 = "" -> (known after apply)
      ~ load_balancing_algorithm_type      = "round_robin" -> (known after apply)
        name                               = "pro-tableau-group"
      + preserve_client_ip                 = (known after apply)
      ~ protocol_version                   = "HTTP1" -> (known after apply)
        tags                               = {
            "Name" = ""
        }
      ~ target_type                        = "ip" -> "instance" # forces replacement
        # (8 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ health_check {
          ~ matcher             = "200" -> (known after apply)
            # (8 unchanged attributes hidden)
        }

      ~ stickiness {
          ~ cookie_duration = 86400 -> (known after apply)
          ~ enabled         = false -> (known after apply)
          ~ type            = "lb_cookie" -> (known after apply)
        }
    }

  # module.ec2.aws_lb_target_group_attachment.tableau-attachment will be created
  + resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "tableau-attachment" {
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + port             = 80
      + target_group_arn = (known after apply)
      + target_id        = ""
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

Comment: Can you show the plan output?

Comment: @jellycsc added :)

Comment: Shoudn't `create_before_destroy = true`?

Comment: @Marcin Tried and seems to be working! thx

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind, I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused by the incorrect value of `create_before_destroy`. Setting it to true solved the problem:

```
create_before_destroy = true
```